# Connecting Python Script with C# in real time

Tags: c#, python, deep-learning

I am working on a project, where I need to run python script real time in C# front end. I try it using command line arguments, where each time I need arguments and it is slow procedure.

Basically I am using trained model of neural network in the C# application. For which I need to use trained model in python because C# does not support deep learning for the most. I want that, is there any why such as socket programming or something else that python script sent me a value in real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to the value be send from python to c# in real time you would need a socket connection, yes.

But you actually don't need things like that, you could use a database as interface for the data, something like influxdb, rethinkdb, even mongo...

another possibility worth checking is https://grpc.io/ RPC frameworks